# IIS App Pools crashing immediately when set to .NET 2.0 & Integrated Pipeline

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net

We've recently started having an issue where all of our app pools set to .NET 2.0 and Integrated mode are crashing immediately upon starting.

Nothing makes it to the IIS log, but the HTTPERR log shows the same thing every time:

```
Line 2084: 2013-11-15 01:33:39 10.71.21.242 57020 192.168.16.26 80 HTTP/1.1 GET / - 129 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue test
```

I've run DebugDiag and hit the site, and get back some relatively useless info as far as I can tell:

```
 In w3wp__test__PID__5196__Date__11_14_2013__Time_03_16_34PM__253__Second_Chance_Exception_E0434352.dmp the assembly instruction at KERNELBASE!RaiseException+3d in C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused a CLR Exception on thread 8
```

The stack trace of that thread:

```
Full Call Stack



Function     Arg 1     Arg 2     Arg 3     Arg 4   Source 
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+3d     000007fe`f9c6839c     00000000`01aed5f8     00000000`00000100     412e6d65`74737800    
MSVCR110_CLR0400!_ValidateExecute+718     00000000`00000000     00000000`01aee470     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
ntdll!RtlRestoreContext+2e2     00000000`00000000     00000000`029b15f0     00000000`029511d0     00000000`01aeee50    
clr!StrongNameTokenFromAssemblyEx+11b636     0000b6b5`b887dd2b     000007fe`00000001     00000000`01aeeeb0     00000000`01aee8e8    
clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+6749     0000b6b5`b887dd2b     00000000`00000000     ffffffff`80004000     00000000`00000000    
clr!CopyPDBs+8337     00000000`00bbfe20     00000000`0215cb50     000007fe`fb736a10     00000000`00000000    
webengine!GetEcb+1ebe     00000000`0215cb50     00000000`010a28e8     00000000`0215cb50     00000000`00000000    
webengine!GetEcb+27a1     00000000`0127e49c     00000000`00000000     00000000`00346b70     00000000`0106d520    
iiscore+113f     00000000`01292648     00000000`01094c70     00000000`00000000     00000000`010a28e0    
iiscore!GetProtocolManager+189eb     00000000`01094c70     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`01292648    
iiscore+15d54     00000000`0127e494     00000000`00000012     00000000`00002710     00000000`00000000    
iiscore+7cd8     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
iiscore+a468     00000000`01292640     00000000`01291a80     00000000`01292640     00000000`00000000    
iiscore+ab24     00000000`00000000     00000000`01291a20     00000000`00000000     00000000`0106b400    
w3dt!UlAtqGetContextProperty+c2     00000000`0106b400     00000000`00000000     000007fe`f14f0000     00000000`0019aa90    
w3dt!UlAtqGetContextProperty+8c     00000000`00000000     000007fe`fd833835     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
w3tp+1fba     00000000`000005ff     00000000`01291a28     000007fe`fb901080     00000000`00000000    
w3tp+2024     00000000`00000000     00000000`0033fc40     00000000`0033fc40     000007fe`f14f0000    
w3tp+20a1     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+d     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+21     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000
```

I am unable to run WinDbg on this as I can't get to the process fast enough before it crashes.

I'm not really sure what could be causing these with these two specific settings set (if I change to .NET 4.0 -OR- change to Classic mode, sites will work).

Worth noting too: This is happening independant of the site running in each app pool - it's happening for Sitecore, Umbraco and static sites (including a hello world app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lengthy support ticket with Microsoft, this turned out to be the result of the following key being set to 1:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\OnlyUseLatestCLR
```

Setting it back to 0 solved the issue.